# Generate AES 128 bits pdf in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am developing an Windows application which will generate pdf files using crystal report. This files needs to be encrypted using aes 128 bits.  I have tried to use pdfsharp dll for the same. However  this encrypts file in RC4 128 level.
Can anybody help me to generate pdf in AES 128 bits?

Below is my code to generate 128 bits RC4 encryption.

```
Dim st as System.io.stream = crreport. ExportTostream (ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat)
Dim document  as pdfdocument = pdfreader.open  (st)
Dim sec as PdfSecuritySettings = document. Security Settings
Sec.userpassword  = "1234"
Sec.ownerpassword ="1234"
Sec.permitPrint = True
document.save (strFileName)
```

Please also share link to download third party dll if required.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I Have downloaded  itexsharp (5.5.6) .It has features to encrypt pdf with Aes128 bits level.
Below is my code for the same.

```
Dim st as system.io.stream = crRpt.ExportToStream (ExportFormatType.PortableDocDormat)
Dim reader as PdfReader = new PdfReader (st)
Dim output = new FileStream (file_name, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAcces.Write)
Dim stamper as pdfStamper = new PdfStamper (reader,output)
Dim password as string ="user"
Stamper.setEncryption (pdfwriter.encryprion_aes_128,password,password,pdfwriter.Allow_degraded_printing)
Stamper.close()
Reader.close ()
```